# BroadcastReceiver does not work

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to create some simple `BroadcastReceiver` according to manuals but I can't to make it work.
I'm calling procedure setAlarm in `onCreate` function in MainActivity that looks like this:

```
private void setAlarm() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

It should activate `AlarmReceiver` that should do some action but doesn't do anything. It looks like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    notifikace(context);
    }

public void notifikace(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new     NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifikace);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
    mBuilder.setContentText("aaa");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)  context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I suspect that I'm missing something in AndroidManifest but I don't know what. AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Nastaveni"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nastaveni"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Tyden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tyden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Ultimately appliacation should be able to send notification every day at certain time even if application isn't running at the moment. (I will have to then replace

```
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, pendingIntent);
```

line with setRepeating function but so far for testing purposes I need first to get it running.)
But so far AlarmReceiver class doesn't do anything. I'm getting some error when I try to run it (but application doesn't crash):

```
04-14 11:52:54.592 1300-1354/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.xxx.myapplication3/com.example.xxx.myapplication.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10014 on display 0
04-14 11:52:54.673 1300-1635/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10057 on display 0
```

I'm not sure whether the error log is related to this or something else in the project. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Format your code/xml please

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem? Mark as correct if so please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I saw later your receiver in manifest, your error is that you ar getting a pending intent with getService instead of getBroadcast.

Just change it to:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

I tried it just now :)

-- edited I will leave this as a reference --

You have to register the receiver somehow, either by code or by xml.

> The alarm is an Intent broadcast that goes to a broadcast receiver that you registered with registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) or through the  tag in an AndroidManifest.xml file.

Refer to:

-[Pending intent - getBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

-[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

-[Triggering alarm and issues](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/scheduling/alarms.html)